# Dynamically set Bootstrap Datepicker value from input like "1996-02-07T00:00:00" format using typescript

Tags: angular6, bootstrap-datepicker, angular-bootstrap

Trying to fetch DateofBirth value from the database which is in this date format:

yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00

I am using Angular6 and bsDatepicker from Bootstrap. When I am binding date value from json to the field, It shows invalid date.

My code looks like this:

I tried using value property of input to set with datepipe alerady

component.html:

```
<input type="text" id="dob" class="form-control" date-placeholder="Date Of Birth" name="dob" [(ngModel)]="dob" #DateofBirth="ngModel" placeholder="Date of Birth" bsDatepicker required/>

json array:
{dob: "1996-02-07T00:00:00"
empcode: "6789"
empfather: "ML "
empid: 1
empname: "Vana"
empphone: "+919898989898"
role: "adminstaff"}
```